# How can I access a request that has been wrapped in a custom class from within my Dropwizard Resource?

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard and I would like to wrap a request object from within a filter, and gain access to that instance from my resource class

e.g. do the following

Filter.java

```
public class ServiceRequestExtractionFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest   = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            ProxyResourceRequest requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper(httpRequest, svcRequestData);

            chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
        }
    }
...
```

Resource.java

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DemoResource {

    @GET
    @Timed
    public Response get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context RequestWrapper request) {

...
```

this doesn't work nor do I have any reason to expect it to, but it seemed like a good way to explain what I was trying to do.

Comment: May I ask what the end goal was? I've not needed to do this before but wondering if there may be an alternative approach I could suggest if I knew what the desired behavior / data was in the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ContainerFilter documented here: http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#jersey-filters

```
public class DateNotSpecifiedFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context ExtendedUriInfo extendedUriInfo;

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
        boolean methodNeedsDateHeader = extendedUriInfo.getMatchedMethod().isAnnotationPresent(DateRequired.class);
        String dateHeader = request.getHeaderValue(HttpHeaders.DATE);

        if (methodNeedsDateHeader && dateHeader == null) {
            Exception cause = new IllegalArgumentException("Date Header was not specified");
            throw new WebApplicationException(cause, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add this in you application run():

```
environment.jersey().getResourceConfig().getContainerRequestFilters().add(new DateNotSpecifiedFilter());
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up working around the problem, and several projects later transitioned o Spring Boot, but better late then never, right?